# How to replace filename whitespace with underscore?

Tags: rename

I have a routine need to replace filename whitespace (space, period, hyphen, etc) with underscore.  Normally, it seems faster to brute-force it with rename than to write a script.

Couple of months ago I found a program that does it perfectly and download it.  I should have named it something sensible, put its path in the path variable, and put a link to it on the desktop so I could locate it.  I didn't, and now I cannot find it because I don't remember its name or location.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: pyRenamer maybe? It's in the Ubuntu repos. GPRename is almost the same as pyRenamer and it's also in the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: Excuse me, didn't read the question properly, answered in a reflex from the title... Deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a many apps that would help you such as [gprename](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gprename)  which i advise your to use

```
sudo apt-get install gprename
```

[image]

As shown in the picture above you can replace whatever with other character easily

you can also try some other apps such as: [krename](http://packages.ubuntu.com/krename) and 
, [pyrenamer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pyrenamer)

Answer (score 0):

A powerful  tool is pyRenamer (Python Renamer).  To install this, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install pyrenamer
```

---

*Screenshot*

[image]